# Change column type with django migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

Consider this structure:

```
some_table(id: small int)
```

and I want change it to this:

```
some_table(id: string)
```

Now I do this with three migrations:

1. Create a new column `_id` with type string
2. (datamigration) Copy data from `id` to `_id` with string conversion
3. Remove id and rename `_id` to `id`

Is there a way to do this with only one migration?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can directly change the type of a column from int to string. Note that, unless strict sql mode is enabled, integers will be truncated to the maximum string length and data is possibly lost, so always make a backup and choose a `max_length` that's high enough. Also, the migration can't easily be reversed (sql doesn't directly support changing a string column to an int column), so a backup is really important in this one.

**Django pre 1.7 / South**

You can use `db.alter_column`. First, create a migration, but don't apply it yet, or you'll lose the data:

```
>>> python manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto
```

Then, change the `forwards` method into this:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.alter_column('some_table', 'id', models.CharField(max_length=255))

    def backwards(self, orm):
        raise RuntimeError('Cannot reverse this migration.')
```

This will alter the column to match the new `CharField` field. Now apply the migration and you're done.

**Django 1.7**
You can use the `AlterField` operation to change the column. First, create an empty migration:

```
>>> python manage.py makemigrations --empty my_app
```

Then, add the following operation:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField('some_model', 'id', models.CharField(max_length=255))
    ]
```

Now run the migration, and Django will alter the field to match the new `CharField`.

Comment: Does it work the same way if I want to change the column type from CharField to IntegerField in Django 1.11?