# django SplitDateTimewidget deprecated

Tags: django

I'm using widgets.AdminSplitDateTime in a create view that is corresponding to a datetime field.

When I try to create the object it gives me the following error:

```
RemovedInDjango19Warning: Using SplitDateTimeWidget with DateTimeField is deprecated. Use SplitDateTimeField instead.
```

I have searched the web for an answer about how to use it but I couldn't find anything that works..

I tries to change the widgets.AdminSplitDateTime to forms.SplitDateTimeField and it gave me the following error:

```
'SplitDateTimeField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'
```

can someone help me on figuring out how to use it?

Comment: You need to replace `DateTimeField` (i.e. the field, not the widget) with `SplitDateTimeField`

Comment: you mean to replace the model field? i.e. from models.DateTimeField to SplitDateTimeField ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what the depreciation message suggests you do.

Comment: when i changed the models.DateTimeField it deleted the corresponding fields from the db..

Comment: That's just matter of having right migrations. If it is the case that the `makemigrations` command creates for you a migration that deletes the old column and adds a new one (instead of altering it in place) you should create your own correct migration, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385118/change-column-type-with-django-migrations (the bottom "Django 1.7" part of the answer).

Comment: @LudwikTrammer `SplitDateTimeField` is a **form** field, not a **model** field.  Changing the `DateTimeField` model field to a `SplitDateTimeField` form field and migrating will drop the column from the db.

Comment: @Alasdair You are right. My bad.